# Copying Multiple Files in TCL using glob

Tags: copy, tcl, glob

I want to copy all files from one folder using tcl.
This is the code that I have written so far, but it does not work. What is the problem?

```
set files [glob -dir E:\Music *]
puts "Moving files"

foreach f { $files } {
    file copy $f E:\
}
```

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem? What is working and what not?

Comment: error copying "$files": no such file or directory

Comment: OK, just lose the braces around `$files` in the `foreach` invocation.

Comment: It is best when you ask a question to say what you see about things not working. In the case of Tcl, it (usually) gives a helpful error message; including that in your question makes it much easier to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

My earlier assumption was wrong, and I unfortunately didn't notice that you were using braces around `$files`. Unlike languages like C, where parentheses or braces are part of syntactic constructions, braces are used for quoting in Tcl. In this case, `$files` is the list of files found by `glob`, while `{ $files }` is the literal string " $files ". Since there is no file named " $files ", you get an error when you try to copy it.

You are still going to have problems with the backslash character. During the phase when the interpreter prepares a command for evaluation, any backslash character is read as a part of an "escape sequence". Changing the backslash character to a regular slash (`E:\` -> `E:/`) may solve your problem. You can also quote it like this `E:\\` or like this `{E:/}`. In the latter case, the braces must enclose the whole string, so it would be `{E:\Music}`.

(Note: the 'Hoodiecrow' mentioned in the comments is me, I used that nick earlier.)