# Set a variable to a filename using glob

Tags: tcl, glob

I have a directory that contains another directory named `ABC_<version number>`

I'd like to set my path to whatever `ABC_<version number>` happens to be (in a modulefile)

How do I use glob in TCL to get the name of the directory I want and put it into a TCL variable?

Thanks!

Comment: is this useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/28515131/587365 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/40148872/587365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glob` command expands wildcards, but produces a Tcl list of everything that matches, so you need to be a bit careful. What's more, the order of the list is “random” — it depends on the raw order of entries in the OS's directory structure, which isn't easily predicted in general — so you really need to decide what you want. Also, if you only want a single item of the list, you *must* use `lindex` (or `lassign` in a degenerate operation mode) to pick it out: otherwise your code will blow up when it encounters a user who puts special characters (space, or one of a small list of other ones) in a pathname. It pays to be safe from the beginning.

For example, if you want to only match a single element and error out otherwise, you should do this:

```
set thePaths [glob -directory $theDir -type d ABC_*]
if {[llength $thePaths] != 1} {
    error "ambiguous match for ABC_* in $theDir"
}
set theDir [lindex $thePaths 0]
```

If instead you want to sort by the version number and pick the (presumably) newes, you can use `lsort -dictionary`. That's pretty magical internally (seriously; read the docs if you want to see what it really does), but does the right thing with all sane version number schemes.

```
set thePaths [glob -directory $theDir -type d ABC_*]
set theSortedPaths [lsort -dictionary -decreasing $thePaths]
set theDir [lindex $theSortedPaths 0]
```

You could theoretically make a custom sort by the actual date on the directories, but that's more complex and can sometimes surprise when you're doing system maintenance.

---

Notice the use of `-type d` in `glob`. That's a *type filter*, which is great in this case where you're explicitly only wanting to get directory names back. The other main useful option there (in general) is `-type f` to get only real files.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was:

```
 set abc_path [glob -directory $env(RELDIR) ABC_*]
```

No need for quotes around the path.  The `-directory controls` where you look.

Later in the modulefile

```
 append-path PATH $abc_path
```

Comment: What if that glob returns multiple directories? Do you need to `append-path PATH [join $abc_path :]`? Caveat, I don't know how module files work, so "append-path" may already do it.